# EntityNotFoundException: Bean has been deleted - lazy loading failed

Tags: java, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.1

I'm making my first steps with the Play! Framework (v2.1-rc1) with Java and now I've faced my first problem with ebean. I have a navigation entity with a ManyToOne relationship to itself. As soon as I try to access the title field in a parentNavigation, I get the following error:

`[EntityNotFoundException: Bean has been deleted - lazy loading failed]`

As I found out, the error only appears if the parent navigation does not exist in the database. Shouldn't I receive an empty navigation object in this case?

Navigation Entity:

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import play.db.ebean.*;

@Entity
public class Navigation extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Column(name="c_title")
    public String title;

    @Column(name="id_parent")
    public Long parentId;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="id_parent")
    public Navigation parentNavigation;

    public static Finder<Long,Navigation> find = new Finder<Long,Navigation>(
        Long.class, Navigation.class
    );
}
```

My action in the controller:

```
public static Result index() {
    Navigation navigation = Navigation.find.byId(2L); // this one doesn't work, but the entry with ID 30 does
    return ok(views.html.app.index.render(navigation));
}
```

And my view:

```
@(navigation: Navigation)

@main("Welcome to Play 2.0") {

    This navigation: @navigation.title <br>
    Parent: @navigation.parentNavigation.title 

}
```

Comment: Show us how do you try to get the object and access the parent

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a row with its `parent_id` column containing `2` (for example), but there is no row with ID `2` in the table.

If so, then it's normal to get an exception. Clean your data by setting all those inexistent `parent_id` to NULL, and add a foreign key constraint to the `parent_id` column so that this situation never happens anymore.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my problem. Sadly, I have to work with the database as it is, so I'm not able to add a foreign key. Is there any other way?

Comment: There is a way with Hibernate with its NotFound annotation, but I don't know if EBean supports such a thing. It's not standard JPA. Note that the absence of a foreign key is not what causes the problem. The problem is caused by incoherences in the data, that a foreign key would help avoiding in the future. What prevents you from removing these incorrect references to unexisting rows in the database? They're not usable by anybody anyway.

Comment: Sure, I could set id_parent to NULL if the parent doesn't exist anymore. But since I have to work with a third-party CMS for the back-end, this problem will happen all the time. Something like a NotFound annotation doesn't exist, at least my Google search told me so. Maybe I have to drop EBean and switch to JPA? I'm really lost. :/

Comment: It the third-party CMS is what creates those data incoherences, that's what I would dump.

Comment: But that's not possible, I have to use it. ;) As I know, the reason why the CMS is doing this, is because of it's versioning. Nevertheless I think EBean should be able to handle this without throwing an error. I also tried .Net Entity Framework and it just returned null for non-existing parents.

Answer (score 1):

In very general it's always better to check if relation isn't null before trying to access it:

```
This navigation: @navigation.title <br>
Parent: @if(navigation.parentNavigation != null){@navigation.parentNavigation.title} else {This nav has no parent}
```

Of course you can skip the `else` clause if it isn't required