# Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Bean has been deleted - lazy loading failed

Tags: playframework, ebean

EDIT: Additional information:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[EntityNotFoundException: Bean has been deleted - lazy loading failed]]
2015-11-23T04:48:23.432891+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
 2015-11-23T04:48:23.432891+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
2015-11-23T04:48:23.432893+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
2015-11-23T04:48:23.432894+00:00 app[web.1]:    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
2015-11-23T04:48:23.432895+00:00 app[web.1]:    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.4.jar:na]
2015-11-23T04:48:23.432896+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Bean has been deleted - lazy loading failed
2015-11-23T04:48:23.432897+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBeanIntercept.loadBeanInternal(EntityBeanIntercept.java:516) ~[org.avaje.ebeanorm.avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
2015-11-23T04:48:23.432898+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBeanIntercept.loadBean(EntityBeanIntercept.java:480) ~[org.avaje.ebeanorm.avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
2015-11-23T04:48:23.432899+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.avaje.ebean.bean.EntityBeanIntercept.preGetter(EntityBeanIntercept.java:583) ~[org.avaje.ebeanorm.avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
2015-11-23T04:48:23.432899+00:00 app[web.1]:    at models.Album._ebean_get_artist(Album.java:4)
2015-11-23T04:48:23.432900+00:00 app[web.1]:    at models.Album.getArtist(Album.java)
```

EDIT: Added parts of the Album definition:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public Long id;
@Column(length = 254)
@Constraints.MaxLength(254)
@NotNull
public String name;
@Column(name = "fullname", length = 254)
@Constraints.MaxLength(254)
@NotNull
public String fullName;
public Integer year;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "artist")
public Artist artist;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "album")
@OrderBy("name asc")
public List<Song> songs = Lists.newArrayList();
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "originalAlbum")
@OrderBy("name asc")
public List<Song> covers = Lists.newArrayList();
```

I've looked at [EntityNotFoundException: Bean has been deleted - lazy loading failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779600/entitynotfoundexception-bean-has-been-deleted-lazy-loading-failed)

There must be some corrupt data somewhere. However, as the models I'm working with are quite complex, I'm at a loss of where to begin to debug.

Any tips? <s>(Play Framework 2.3, Avaje Ebean 3.1.1)</s> Upgraded to Play Framework 2.4, still the same issue.

Comment: Exactly what version of Ebean is it?

Comment: Avaje-ebean 3.1.1 http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.avaje.ebeanorm/avaje-ebeanorm-api/3.1.1

Comment: I think that is an Ebean bug (assuming the bean truely has not been deleted). You should ideally migrate up to at least 4.x but latest versions are 6.10.x.

Comment: Do you see this issue with the lastest Play Framework (2.4.4 right now) and the latest version of Ebean (6.11.1 right now)?

Comment: Can you share the Album entity definition?

Comment: @JanNielsen - I'm on 2.3.7, and haven't gotten a chance to upgrade EBean, I will be looking to up the Ebean version shortly. I'll add the album def soon

Comment: @JanNielsen Upgraded to play 2.4.4 and I still see the issue, thanks for taking the time though

Comment: Create a test case without Play involved, log it with the Ebean project and I'll look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the process I use for finding the root cause of ORM problems:

1. identify entity(ies) expressed in the symptom(s);
2. identify entity(ies) related-to the entity(ies) expressed in the symptoms;
3. identify the related-to entity(ies) ORM model;
4. identify the data-store entity(ies) model; and,
5. reconcile entity, ORM, and data models.

Mapping this process to your problem:

1. in the stack trace we see that `Album` is expressed in the symptom (i.e., your stack trace);
2. review the entity definition for `Album` to identity related-to entities;
3. for each related-to entity, identify how your EBean ORM model is represented;
4. for each of these entities, identity the SQL model; and,
5. from this data, reconcile differences.

As noted in the comments, it's very possible that you're hitting an ORM bug. If possible, it's likely well worth your time to upgrade to the latest stable versions of Play and EBean before doing anything else even if you can't do this in production.